# How to optimize these parameter

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

How to optimize the following with respect to $\lambda_1$ and
$\lambda_2$:

$\sum_{i} f(i) \cdot \log(\lambda_1 g(i) + \lambda_2 h(i))$,

where $f(i)$, $g(i)$, and $h(i)$ are known funtions.

Find $\lambda_1$ and
$\lambda_2$ that satisfy $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = 1$ and maximize the expression.

Is there any close-form solution or algorithm to find them?

Comment: I've removed the "convex-optimization" label, because this most certainly is not convex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have as objective function $$\Phi(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)=\sum_{i} f_i * \log(\lambda_1 g_i + \lambda_2 h_i)$$ and, since you want that at solution  $\lambda_1 +\lambda_2=1$, extract $\lambda_2$ from this constraint and then consider $$\Psi(\lambda_1)=\sum_{i} f_i * \log\big(\lambda_1 g_i + (1-\lambda_1) h_i\big)$$ Since you want $\Psi$ to be maximum,$$\frac {d\Psi(\lambda_1)}{d\lambda_1}=\sum_{i}\frac {f_i(g_i-h_i)}{\lambda_1(g_i-h_i)+h_i}=0$$ So, you have to solve a single equation for a single unknown. This equation represents a sum of hyperbolas with $i$ asymptotes; so you have many roots but between two hyperbolas, you cane use a root-finder algorithm (what I would suggest is a combination of Newton steps and bissections steps in a permanentely updated interval).

If you want me to elaborate more on this topic, just post. This is the kind of equations I worked for decades.

Comment: The problem I face changed, now I want to optimize $\sum_{i} f(i) \log(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \lambda_k f_k(i))$ respect to $\lambda_k$ with the requirement $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \lambda_k= 1$ and $\lambda_k > 0 \; \forall k$. Can you give some ideas how to deal with this problem?

Comment: Lagrange multipliers seems to be the way.